# How to make a progress bar to pause immediately on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a progress bar that has a duration.

The problem is when I hover over the progress bar it doesn't stop immediately on hover, it goes a little bit further then it stops.

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/24n6mx299n) I have created, which has the problem I described. ( click on start button then hover over the progress bar)

How can I make it to stop immediately on hover?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It was a css problem with bootstrap.. sometimes a problem is in-front of your eyes and you cant see it.